# Does it make sense to make multiple SQLite databases to improve performance?

Tags: sqlite

I'm just learning SQL/SQLite, and plan to use SQLite 3 for a new website I'm building.  It's replacing XML, so concurrency isn't a big concern.  But I would like to make it as performant as possible with the technology I'm using.  Are there any benefits to using multiple databases for performance, or is the best performance keeping all the data for the site in one file?  I ask because 99% of the data will be read-only 99% of the time, but that last 1% will be written to 99% of the time.  I know databases don't read in and re-write the whole file for every little change, but I guess I'm wondering if the writes will be much faster if the data is going to a separate 5KB database, rather than part of the ~ 250MB main database.

Answer (score 2):

With proper performance tuning, sqlite can do around [63 300 inserts-per-second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite). Unless you're planning on some really heavy volume, I would avoid pre-optimizing. Splitting into two databases doesn't feel right to me, and if you're planning on doing joins in the future, you'll be hosed. Especially since you say concurrency isn't a big problem, I would avoid complicating the database design.

Comment: I don't think I'd bother with any joins.  The small database would just be used for storing view counters for various pages.  Since the data would be retrieved and incremented with every view, I was thinking that it would be faster to read and write data to a tiny database, then to have it read from a giant database that has tons of other data in it.  That was my thinking at least.

Comment: Also, a lot of my queries to the big database could take a while... like a few seconds each.  Does it matter if it's occasionally trying to do multiple big SELECTs at the same time, and writing the increment counter as well to the same database?  I guess that's my bigger question... it's sort of concurrency related, but the site really won't get that many hits.

Comment: Thats a good point. It would be worth looking into how the write locks work for sqlite. Honestly, I see nothing wrong with your approach of using two databases if they do not share any common data that needs to be queried together. If the writing is going to end up locking the database frequently then it seems like a good idea to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with 50 000 databases you will have very bad performance

you should try several tables in single database, sometimes it really can speed up something, but as description of initial task is very general - hard to say exactly what you need, try single table and multiple tables - measure speed

Comment: Well, I was thinking I would use two databases.  One big one that's mostly read-only, and one tiny one that's written to a lot ("a lot" being maybe a dozen times a minute or so).

Comment: for such case - this is good approach, but why you need database at all? maybe simple files will work too?

Comment: Hmm... cause people on Stackoverflow and Reddit said I'd be crazy to build a website with a lot of data throughput and thousands of hits every day and not use a database? :-p  Honestly... the system I'm replacing using XML was having occasional concurrency issues, which could probably be fixed in the redesign with redesigned XML schema, instead of having giant files being read from and written to a lot, but people talked me into using a database, and SQLite seemed like a good compromise.

Comment: if your system functionality is about multiple xml files - then I really suggest you to use xml files, instead of database, of course you will need to think about backup then

Comment: Well, I guess I was sold on the relational part of the database model.  It's a music site I'm working on, and with the XML system, I have a lot of duplicate data.  On the users profile XML file, there's the list of the bands they like.  On the bands profile XML file, there's a list of the users that like them.  And if the user changes their preference, I change it in both locations.  Slower to write, but faster to read in either case... when compared to an XML solution that just keeps the data in one place.

Comment: I suggest you to go with ordinary db structure then, but have some kind of cache (it can be xml/memcache/redis/mongo) which will be updated only when something in db is changed

Comment: Please forgive my novice.  What qualifies as "ordinary db structure"?  How are you suggesting using the cache? As in.. what would be stored in it?  When you say it "will be updated only when something in db is changed", that's taking into account the fact there will be updates pretty regularly?

Comment: I suppose answer can take a whole book..., by ordinary I mean 3 tables in db, cache - can be event place on harddrive, or in memory (like memcache), updates in your system usually will take only small percentage of reads, so such "double write" (into db and into cache) will not provide big overhead

Comment: Oh... there's going to be a lot of tables.  Probably dozens in the main table.  For the view counter table (the smaller one that will get lots of writes), I could probably get away with one table, though I may divide it up into categories and have maybe a half dozen tables.  I'm not sure if this affects your advice at all.